# Performance issue with rending RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

we are using rdlc report in my mvc.net application. We are able to fetch the data withing few second when it is taking more than 5 minutes to render that report. We have used the same report in Crystal report and it was taking only 1 minutes to render that report. However, we have used grouping in the report but I believe that rdlc report should be faster than crystal report. Could you please suggest any idea to improve the performance of this report.

```
    reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
reportViewer.AsyncRendering = true;
reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
reportViewer.Width = U`enter code here`nit.Pixel(350);
reportViewer.Height = Unit.Pixel(50);
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();

reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet";

reportDataSource.Value = result;

reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"\ReportsrptReport.rdlc";        
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

TempData["FileData"] = bytes;
TempData["MimeType"] = mimeType;
TempData["FileName"] = fileName;

return File(bytes, mimeType, fileName);
```

Comment: We came to know the issue due to the rending of PDF file. Since there are more than 1000 pages of the PDF in the RDLC therefore it is taking too much time. But the same PDF feature is working very fast with the Crystal Report. There must be some solution for this.

Comment: try to move any functions or conditions from report level to database level. this will minimize the report processing (database level can be optimized).
alse send minimum data from database.

Answer (score 2):

[rdlc performance blog for more details](https://travis.io/blog/2014/10/27/rdlc-performance-issues-dotnet45/)

1. Remove all the expressions in SSRS report
2. try asp.net 3.5 or 4.0 framework on a subdomain as you as you are using MVC.
3. returning datatable as datasource runs much faster than a list of objects.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to improve the RDLC performance at acceptable speed level after my 5 months investigation. RDLC is created for SIMPLE report such as receipt and invoice. Using html is the best option for acceptable loading and rendering speed if the number of report pages is greater than 100 with no any internal expressions, or greater than 50 pages with dynamic internal expressions.